# minify external url & multiple style sheets

Tags: javascript, html, css, minify

2 part problem whilst using minify. Finally got it working on localhost.

1) I have some scripts which can be linked externally to CDN, how do i include these in the minify?

```
         <script type="text/javascript" src="/min/b=highaccess/js&amp;f=styleswitcher.js,jquery-1.7.2.js,jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.min.js,downloadxml.js,geometa.js"></script>
```

I also need to include this:http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAOpIKcVcsbojjjFIwnAOSsDwi_lARLp8o&sensor=false

If possible i will use hosted scripts.

2) I have managed to minify the CSS, but i have a style switcher for 3 layouts, when i include them in the minify they cascade, not what i intended. Is there a way to minify this or must I have seperate elements for each style?

Answer (score 1):

1) Minifying the external assets from a CDN kinda defeats the purpose of using a CDN in the first place. You're offloading the content to another server and you gain the benefit of having those files being likely to have been cached already (downloaded when a user visits a site using the same CDN as you). If you must have them minified, just get your own local copy and include it in your minify script. Otherwise, I would just leave them as separate script calls.

2) Minifying CSS means that everything is combined into a single request, so yes, styles added later will override the earlier styles. If you have 3 separate themes, you'll need to have 3 separate minification processes for each theme. Just load them dynamically in  tags with javascript and they will override at the time you switch.

Comment: Think i get you, as for (1) i shall use CDN's where possible and minify the other j/s and ignore Yslow's warnings. 

(2) Any unset properties in the base2.css come through from base.css and alternative.css. (base2.css is the default atm, please dont ask why) also the style switcher no longer works, this is the code for the style switcher: http://jsfiddle.net/VF3eX/